# How to send digitally signed email in c# using EASend mail dll

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, digital-signature

It is possible to send digitally sign an  email and send it to recipient using EASendmail in c# from Visual studio while debugging the code.But when i publish it in server email sending is sending but it is not getting digitally signed.For signing i have installed a sample pfx certificate which i have created by using pfx certificate generator.IIs can't access the certificate from current user personal certificate store.

Please help me to solve the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pfx certificate can be installed in two ways.

1. Directly clicking the certificate then a certificate wizard will be opened.By filling the data's in wizard we can install the certificate.
2. Using certificate manager snap-in.
   Install the certificate to local machine by using certificate snap-in.
3. types of installation available
   a. Current user
   b. Local machine
   c. Current service
   Install certificate under local machine.